# Remove hyperlink for lookup field in SharePoint2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, jquery

Can any one give example to remove Hyper Link for lookup field in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: can you add more description?

Comment: Would you please elaborate. What are you using is it in  webpart, dataview, gridview??

Comment: It is custom list only

Answer (score 3):

Where are you using the field? Presumably a web part, but what kind? How does jQuery feature in this?

The answer is that it depends on the context in which you are using the field. The techniques to suppress a hyperlink depend on the method you use to display the field.